# Visual Studio 2015 - TextEditor formatting - newline after get in property

Tags: visual-studio-2015, productivity-power-tools

When typing code in **Visual Studio 2015**, **C#**, **Productivity Power Tools** installed, text editor automatically adds newline after typing semicolon in getter.

So code

```
public string Street { get
```

after typing semicolon (;) becomes

```
public string Street {
            get;
```

I have found that this can be changed by turning off
**Options -> Text Editor -> C# ->Formatting -> General -> Automatically format statement on;**

Is there a way to keep Auto-formatting on semicolon, but to keep **get; set;** on same line when typing? Auto-formatting is excellent helper, only this one feature annoys me.